# React: set all objects keys in state to false

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have React Component with state:

```
this.state={
            items: [
                {
                    label: '1 Some text',
                    active: true
                },
                {
                    label: '2 Some text',
                    active: false
                },
                {
                    label: '3 Some text',
                    active: false
                },
                {
                    label: '4 Some text',
                    active: false
                }
            ]
        }
```

I have a menu, when I click on it, I would like to change the state:

```
this.state.items.map(item => {
                return <li onClick={}>{item.label}</li>
            })
```

If I click on any of the menu items, I want to make it `active: true`, and set all others to `active: false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update:

```
 manuOnClick=(e, label)=>{
     let newState = this.state.items.map(item=>{
             if(label === item.label)
             {   
                 let newItem={
                     label:label,
                     active:true
                 }
                 return newItem   
             }
             else
             {
                 let newItem={
                     label:item.label,
                     active:false
                 }
                 return newItem 
             }
     })

     this.setState({
          items:newState
     })
}
```

### Sorry,

`onClick={(e,item.label)=>this.manuOnClick(e,item.label)`

is not correct, it should be

`onClick={(e)=>this.manuOnClick(e,item.label)`

Try this :

```
manuOnClick=(e, label)=>{
     let newState = this.state.items.map(item=>{
             if(label === item.label)
             {   
                 let newItem={
                     label:label,
                     active:true
                 }
                 return newItem   
             }
             else
             {
                 return item
             }
     })

     this.setState({
          items:newState
     })
}



this.state.items.map(item => {
            return <li onClick={(e)=>this.manuOnClick(e,item.label)}>{item.label}</li>
        })
```

Comment: ty! this function selects a new item menu, but does not make the rest inactive :(

Comment: I corrected the code a bit, thanks for the idea, the problem is solved!

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use `this.setState`:
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

I would highly recommend considering splitting this component out into different components, one per item, each with it's own state management. Is there a reason the state for all of them need to be managed at this parent level? Simpler is better than complex.

That being said, if you do move forward and decide that you need it at this level, I'd recommend some thing like the following for each onClick:

```
this.setState((state) => {
    const itemsCopy = state.items.slice();

    itemsCopy[itemIndex].active = true;    

    return { items: itemsCopy }; 
});
```